# Can't port as3 code (arrays) to c# (list?)

Tags: c#, actionscript-3, xna, monogame

I'm tried to port this code:
http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2008/12/08/perfect-maze-generation-tile-based-version-as3/
to c#, and write it with XNA.

But I got broken maze:
[image]

I'm new to c#, maybe someone can help me?

Here is my C# code (I remove draw method):

```
class Maze 
{
    private int MAZE_WIDTH = 30;
    private int MAZE_HEIGHT = 30;
    private int TILE_SIZE = 10;

    private int _width;
    private int _height;
    private int [,] _maze;
    private List<int> _moves;

    private int _startX;
    private int _startY;
    private int _finishX;
    private int _finishY;

    public Maze()
    {
        _width = MAZE_WIDTH *2 - 1;
        _height = MAZE_HEIGHT *2 - 1;
        _startX = 1;
        _startY = 1;
        _finishX = _height - 2;
        _finishY = _height - 2;

        Generate();
    }

    public void Generate()
    {
        InitMaze();
        CreateMaze();
    }

    private void InitMaze()
    {
        _maze = new int[_width, _height];
        for (var x = 0; x < _height; x++)
        {                                
            for (var y = 0; y < _width; y++)
                _maze[x, y] = 1;
        }

        _maze[_startX, _startY] = 0;
    }


    private void CreateMaze()
    {
        var posX = _startX;
        var posY = _startY;
        _moves = new List<int>();
        _moves.Add(posY + (posX*_width));


        while (_moves.Count > 0)
        {
            string possibleDirections = "";

            if ((posX + 2 < _height) && (_maze[posX + 2, posY] == 1) && (posY + 2 != 0) && (posX + 2 != _height - 1))
            {
                possibleDirections += "S";
            }
            if ((posX - 2 >= 0) && (_maze[posX - 2, posY] == 1) && (posX - 2 != 0) && (posX - 2 != _height - 1))
            {
                possibleDirections += "N";
            }
            if ((posY - 2 >= 0) && (_maze[posX, posY - 2] == 1) && (posY - 2 != 0) && (posY - 2 != _width - 1))
            {
                possibleDirections += "W";
            }
            if ((posY + 2 < _width) && (_maze[posX, posY + 2] == 1) && (posY + 2 != 0) && (posY + 2 != _width - 1))
            {
                possibleDirections += "E";
            }


            if (possibleDirections.Length > 0)
            {

                var move = Utils.RandInt(0, (possibleDirections.Length - 1));

                switch (possibleDirections[move].ToString())
                {
                    case "N":
                        _maze[posX - 2, posY] = 0;
                        _maze[posX - 1, posY] = 0;
                        posX -= 2;
                        break;
                    case "S":
                        _maze[posX + 2, posY] = 0;
                        _maze[posX + 1, posY] = 0;
                        posX += 2;
                        break;
                    case "W":
                        _maze[posX,posY - 2] = 0;
                        _maze[posX,posY - 1] = 0;
                        posY -= 2;
                        break;
                    case "E":
                        _maze[posX,posY + 2] = 0;
                        _maze[posX,posY + 1] = 0;
                        posY += 2;
                        break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                var back = _moves[_moves.Count - 1];
                _moves.RemoveAt(_moves.Count - 1);

                posX = back/_width;
                posY = back%_width;
            }
        }            
    }


    public void DrawMaze(ScreenBase screen)
    {
        //just drawing tiles
    }

    private int RandInt(int min, int max)
    {
        return new Random().Next(min, max);
    }

    //End of class
}



class Utils
{

    private static readonly Random rnd = new Random();
    public static int RandInt(int min, int max)
    {
        return rnd.Next(min, max);
    }
}
```

Comment: Problem is not in the random value. It is worked propertly.

Answer (score 0):

You're generating a new `Random` object every time you're calling `RandInt()`. When that occurs in quick succession, it uses the same seed since it's based on the system time and you end up getting the same "random" value over and over.

One way to fix it would be to add another field:

```
private Random _random = new Random();
```

And then change your `RandInt()` method to:

```
private int RandInt(int min, int max)
{
    return _random.Next(min, max);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice! I change my code as you recomended. But still maze is broken :(

Comment: @dmitryhryppa It doesn't look broken to me. Just *very* easy. ;)

Comment: But it should be more difficult :D